# Add query time boosting field weightings

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently using elasticsearch version 2.4 and wish to fine tune my result set. I've already implemented constant_score to add relevance based on types.

My documents have the following fields:

- Manufacturer
- Model
- Description
- Year of manufacturer

I wish to add weightings to the relevance weightings to a document field.

For example Manufacturer would have a weighting of 2 and Description a weighting of 1

Then my search results would display those documents with the search term in the Manufacturer field before those with the search term in the Description field.

If someone could provide an example to my scenario to get me going.